# Python - Invalid character after line continuation

Tags: python

I was trying to write a comparison function in Python:

```
a = 1
print(
    "1" if a < 1 else \  # Just testing...
    "2" if a == 1 else \ # Testing whether comments work after backslashes
    "3"                  # Last one!
)
```

After I added these comments, it gave me a Syntax Error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Get rid of the backslashes. They are unnecessary in this case because your lines are inside parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the backslashes. They are unnecessary in this case because your lines are inside parentheses.

```
print(
    "1" if a < 1 else   # <- a < 1
    "2" if a == 1 else  # <- a == 1
    "3"                 # a > 1
)
```

I would also suggest that your comments are not particularly useful, since they're just repeating things in the same line of code, and maybe you don't actually need them.

Comment: I know, I was just checking whether comments work after backslashes. I guess I'd leave the useless comments out.